# Magento Fatal error: Maximum execution error solution, on WAMP

Tags: magento, installation

While installing Magento, on WAMP I was getting timeout errors a lot like

```
  Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in c:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228
```

I have no idea where to look to increase the execution time if needed. Can anyone help with this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

change the following value in your php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 18000
```

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem 
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228
I have increased max_execution_time also but no success.

Comment: @SushilKandola Don't do changes in Pdo.php. Do the change in php.ini file.. which is located in `apache/bin/php.ini` and `php/php.ini` folders in wamp. and just `php/php.ini` in Xampp. That is what I understood from this solution. May be I am wrong though.

Answer (score 3):

You can also adjust the max_execution_time in your htaccess using

```
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be in your PHP ini file `max_execution_time`

[Runtime Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

Answer (score 2):

Try making sure your settings are:

- max_execution_time is 0 and
- max_input_time = 60 --> change max_input_time = 6000
- memory_limit = 128M --> change it to memory_limit = 512MB

after this I re-installed magento and it worked for me.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: In which file? I hope you are mentioning the `php.ini` file. I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, as suggested I did the following changes.

1. ***(wampserver-path)\bin\apache(Apache Version)\bin\php.ini*** - Set the
   value **max_execution_time = 1800**
2. ***(wampserver-path)\bin\php(PHPVersion)\php.ini*** - Set the value
       **max_execution_time = 1800**

But it didn't work. Then I made the next change

- In the ***host/(path-to-magento)/index.php***, just after the opening `<?php`
  tag, added the following. `set_time_limit(1800)`;

> ```
> <?php
> set_time_limit(1800);
> //** Other bunches of code 
> ?>
> ```

Then tried to install a fresh copy. It worked! Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

is this ok or not want is your Recommended ?
max_execution_time = `15000` 
max_input_time = `15000`
session.gc_maxlifetime = `15000`
memory_limit = `-1`
upload_max_filesize = `150`

Answer (score 0):

I did that by deleting the file app\etc\local.xml

Comment: and setting max_execution_time = 18000