# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of x seconds exceeded

Tags: php, magento, phpmyadmin, xampp, magento-1.7

I am not sure whether this problem is related to magento or not.

I downloaded the below files

- magento 1.7.1 version
- XAMPP 1.7.3 win 32 (my laptop is Windows 8 64bit)

First, I installed Xampp and run the apache but due to port 80 unavailability, I changed the default port of apache server to "*9999*".

Later, I extracted the magento in "*htdocs*" folder and run it on firefox like this "*http://localhost:9999/magento*"

A Installation wizard appeared inside the webpage. In the "Configuration" step, I added the following information:

- Database Type = MySQL
- Host = localhost:9999
- Database name = magento
- username = root
- password = (nothing)

I haven't touched the other settings.

Before proceeding, I created a database name "magento" through "*PhpMyAdmin*" and added sample data (.sql file) which I had downloaded from magento.com.

When I pressed the button "continue", after a long time I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in c:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7533232/1577396) and did some changes as follows:

In php/php.ini file: (*changed the following values*)

- max_execution_time = 3600  (default was "60")
- max_input_time = -1        (default was "60")
- memory_limit = 512M        (default was "128M")

and In magento/index.php file added `set_time_limit(600);` at very first after `<?php` line.

After doing the above changes, I am getting different error which is shown below: (In red line)

[image]

I can't understand what could be the problem.

Please help.

**PS**: At first, the installation went smooth but when I am trying to install second time, these issues are arousing.

Comment: Did you restarted your server, so the php.ini changes took effect?

Comment: I even tried by re-installing xampp but with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While installing magento, In "configuration" page --> "*Database connection*" section, I was giving host as `localhost:9999` instead of just `localhost` because PhpMyAdmin was running on `localhost` as shown in the below image.

[image]

This is my stupid mistake. I will keep this as answer because it is a good lesson for me to understand that **there is** difference between the host names of "*Database*" and "*Web server*".

Answer (score 0):

Your database seems to either be slow or you're sending it too many queries.

First you run out of your 60 seconds allotted by the PHP engine. Then, your database times out, or something happens to the connection at least.

Can you give more info on what is the sql file? If it's a large import find another way to do it.

Comment: I downloaded from this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download). `sample data ver 1.6.1.0` section download.

Comment: Could it be problem related to mentioning port number `9999` ? because at first installation, the port number was default.

Comment: I don't see why. Your webserver seems to work, it's the database server that's refusing.

Comment: Check this [image](http://i.imgur.com/fUjvApu.png) the server is localhost but not localhost:9999. I am thinking this could be the problem. but my apache server is not working on default port. I don't know why. (I even closed all apps)

Comment: I got solution. please check below post. Thanks :)